# How to share data between render and componentDidMount in React?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to load different results on my website based on the navigation links clicked by users. I have setup DRF to provide the API endpoints. I am using `React Router v4` to load the data based on the clicks. Here is my code which has a very common problem. I am using `setState`inside `componentDidUpdate`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


const Nav = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to='/'>All</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/medicine'>Medicine</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/capsules'>Capsules</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route path='/:category?' component={Content}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${match.params.category}/`;

    if (!match.params.category) {
      url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    }

    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const items = response.data;
        this.setState({ items });
        console.log('load');
      })
    console.log('mount')
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${match.params.category}/`;

    if (!match.params.category) {
      url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    }

    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const items = response.data;
        // this.setState({ items });
        console.log('load');
      })
    console.log('update')
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <p>
        { this.state.items.map(item => <span key={item.id}>{item.name}<br/></span>) }
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const Main = () => (
  <Nav/>
)

export default Main;
```

How can I update my data without using `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` method?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your initial implementation. You have an async call that requires you to stamp data onto `state` once it arrives. Why not continue to use the `setState` API as intended?

Comment: If I use `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` an infinite loop starts. This is quite common, I just didn't know how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Sorry, completely missed the `componentDidUpdate`. What's your use case for `componentDidUpdate`? This is a rare lifecycle event to hook into. Perhaps you just need `componentWillReceieveProps`

Comment: I have bunch of navigation links. And I need to load content on a div based on the links clicked. `componentDidMount` loads the content for the first time. `componentDidUpdate` loads the content when a user clicks the links. Is my code the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` as long as you have a conditional check. What you need to do is conditionally call the API in `componentDidUpdate` if the category changed.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    const {match: prevMatch} = prevProps;
    const { match } = this.props;
    if(prevMatch.params.category !== match.params.category) {
        let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${match.params.category}/`;

        if (!match.params.category) {
          url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
        }

        axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            const items = response.data;
            // this.setState({ items });
            console.log('load');
          })
        console.log('update')
    }

  }
```

However before `React v16.3.0` you can also make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` to call the API on category change.

Comment: Can you please explain this line to me? `const {match: prevMatch} = prevProps;`

Comment: OK I just read this link `http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_overview-destructuring` and have an idea of `destructuring`. Thanks for the answer.